# Client IP is not preserved, instead it is showing weave network ip

Tags: kubernetes, ip, client, preserve

I have a master and Node in Kubernetes. I tried to create POD with Node Port and also with ExternalIPs as Service Type. In both cases, I am not getting my client IP, which is sending requests to the application which is running inside the pod.

How my application Works:

Client Request will be sent to the Application and the application reads that request and gets the source IP and sync up with client and update the client IP in application.

When I am running my application inside in the pod, the client's IP is updated and POD network IP when I use Service Type as NodePort and Client IP as weave network IP when I use service Type as ExternalIPs.

I want the actual Client IP to be the preserver and I should be getting that Client IP in my application when it gets updated.

Any suggestion please .I am struggling for past 3 days .

Comment: Hi Srivalli Ganesh, welcome to SO. You failed to specify if you have a load balancer in front of your cluster, or whether you are curl-ing directly to the Node (in the case of your NodePort Service)

Comment: No loadbalancer in my k8 cluster. I have created service type as ExternalIP. Meaning Kind is service and used ExternalIPs.

Comment: Can you please update your question with more specifics, including the actual IPs and the output from curl that you are using to test that setup? Please refer to the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and especially the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section, in order to have the best experience here. Help us to help you